# how to make syntastic show current line errors in insert mode in vim?

Tags: vim, syntastic

The title of question is pretty self-explanatory - I want to be able to see syntastic errors on the line I currently positioned my cursor in errors line without switching to normal mode for it.

Comment: @minitech ok, will know, thx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not possible, and there is no plan to implement it, either.  The cursor notification mechanism is already the slowest part of syntastic, by far.  Because of the way redraws work in insert mode, cursor notification in this mode would be an order of magnitude *slower*.  There is simply no reasonable way to implement this reliably and still keep it usable.  Sorry about that.